# undefined reference to ERROR `get_squares'

Tags: c

I have the following simple program I am trying to compile in Dev-C++

`main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "squares.h"

int main() {
    void get_squares(int n, int output[]);
    int n = 10;
    int squares[10];  // Declare an array large enough to hold 10 integers
    get_squares(n, squares);  // Use get_squares to populate the array
    
    // Print each element of the array
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", squares[i]);
    }

    puts("Hello, world!");
    return 0;
}
```

`squares.c`

```
#include "squares.h"

void get_squares(int n, int output[]) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // Modifies the array passed as input
        output[i] = i * i;
    }
}
```

`squares.h`

```
#ifndef SQUARES_H
#define SQUARES_H

void get_squares(int n, int output[]);

#endif
```

Why do I get the following error? I tried to add void get_squares(int n, int output[]); in the main but it does not work.

```
hello.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `get_squares'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You need to _compile_ `squares.c` to get `squares.o` (e.g. `cc -c squares.c`). Then, (e.g.) `cc -o myprogram main.c squares.o`. Or, [less desirable] do: `cc -o myprogram main.c squares.c` You'll have to figure out how to configure `Dev-C` to do the equivalent. Yet another way: `cc -c main.c ; cc -c squares.c ; cc -o myprogram main.o squares.o`

Comment: Do not need `void get_squares(int n, int output[]);` just after main either